# How to read const char * from files

Tags: c, file

I need to `read` a `filename` from a text file. 
Then I have to use it as an argument for `fopen` . 
Consequently , I need to read it as a `const char*` because this is the type `fopen` accepts as a first argument. How do I do this?

I tried something like:

```
 FILE *a;
 a=fopen("a.txt","r");
 const char *filename
 fgets(filename,100,a);
 image=fopen(filename,"rb");
```

Something is be wrong as I receive a segmentation fault when I do this. I think that the variable `filename` is not well-received by the `fopen` function.

Comment: `const char *filename` --> `char filename[100];`. Also If `filename` contains a newline, it is necessary to remove it.

Comment: I know that code is wrong, i want to know the right alternative

Comment: @LazuRazvan I suggest you read up on the usage of constants (`const`) in C. There are tons of results just from googling "Using const in C".

Comment: `fopen` expects a char pointer as argument; the `const` in the formal parameter list only denotes, that the memory contents pointed to will not be changed by `fopen()`.

Comment: The key is not that you're passing `fopen` a `const char*`, but that you're passing it a _pointer to a string_. Your problem is thus how to read a _string_ from a file; try googling that, you should get some sort of `char` array/pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen that `fopen()` takes an argument of type `(const char *)`, but you need to be able to modify your string before you pass it to the function. Also, you need to allocate space for your string, and you might consider allocating space for more than 100 `char`s. The `stdio.h` header file contains the macro `FILENAME_MAX`, which expands to an integer constant of the correct size for an array that will hold the longest possible file name string on a system. For example, you can use `char filename[FILENAME_MAX];`. When the identifier `filename` is encountered in the call to `fopen()`, it decays to a pointer to `char`, which is converted to a pointer to `const char`, as per the function prototype.

Furthermore, `fgets()` keeps the newline when if fetches a line of text, so you will need to remove that. You should check the result of `fgets()`, as it returns a `NULL` pointer in the event of an error or if it is called at end-of-file; otherwise it returns a pointer to the first `char` in `filename[]`.

```
FILE *a;
a=fopen("a.txt","r");
char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
char *ch;

ch = fgets(filename,FILENAME_MAX,a);

/* Remove trailing newline */
if (ch) {
    while (*ch != '\0' && *ch != '\n') {
        ++ch;
    }
    if (*ch == '\n') {                  // replace '\n' with '\0'
        *ch = '\0';
    }
    image=fopen(filename,"rb");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your seg fault likely comes from trying to use memory that you do not own.  i.e. by creating the variable:

```
const char *filename;
```

And not giving it any memory (*[[c][m]alloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)*) before trying to use it.

Regarding your statement:
*Consequently , i need to read it as a const char**.

Not necessarily.
The first argument of the `fopen` prototype:  *["FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)* simply guarantees that the argument passed in that position will be treated as a `const char *` within the `fopen` function.
The argument can be passed using a simple `char *`, eg. either of these forms:

```
char *filename = {"somefilename.txt"};
```

or

```
char filename[80];
strcpy(filename, "somefilename.txt");
```

And, as mentioned in comments, and other answers, remove the newline character, `\n` before passing as an argument.